# Docker with multiple exposed ports

Tags: networking, angular, docker, flask

I have a container with say, 3 ports, 1000 (nodejs-express), 1001 (python-flask) and 1002 (angular2-client) exposed. When I use

```
docker run --name test -d -p 1000:1000 -p 1001:1001 -p 1002:1002 docker_image
```

Only the Express server is working fine on the host computer. However, when I log into the container and do `curl`, all three servers are responding just fine.

Any ideas what is going on with multiple port bindings with docker/host?

Comment: Can you give some details ? What do you mean by not working fine ? Are you not able to reach them or are them not providing you what you wish. Currently, I understand that you can't reach the servers over than express from the Localhost, but they are well running inside the container. Could you give us the return of `docker ps` ?

Comment: Hi Titouan - yes, those ports are not working. I can't reach them. Here is the output of docker ps: CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
25f293fb7dbf        mvangala/bib:0.0.1   "/bin/bash ./run_serv"   19 seconds ago      Up 13 seconds       0.0.0.0:7998-8000->7998-8000/tcp   dockerflow_test

Comment: the ports I'm using are actually 7998,7999 and 8000 (not 1000-1002). Please let me know your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: are the services allowed to accept external connection? i.e. for python flask: http://dixu.me/2015/10/26/How_to_Allow_Remote_Connections_to_Flask_Web_Service/ does it listen on 0.0.0.0?

Comment: flask by default connects to 127.0.0.1 and when I reran with --host 0.0.0.0, it worked. That makes sense. I am not getting angular server to work because it's running in development mode and I presume changing it to prod_mode() should do the job. Thanks much to all of you.

Comment: if you server accept external connections, (thanks @dokkis), perhaps you should change the idea of having 3 servers running in a single container. The purpose of Docker is to have a process per container ;) (multimaping port are not a pb, some official images use it and it is well working when using standard web ports)

Comment: @dokkis could you update your comment as an answer so we can close the subject ? :)

Comment: inserted a comment with the solution. Anyway I agree with @Titouan Freville that you should have one docker container per services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you do the following:

1. EXPOSE ports on the DockerFile
2. set -p flag for each port to expose externally

You just need to make sure that your services allows external connections.

i.e. for python flask: http://dixu.me/2015/10/26/How_to_Allow_Remote_Connections_to_Flask_Web_Service/ the default listen is localhost. Make sure it's listening on 0.0.0.0